# D3.js, position elements horizontally

Tags: d3.js

I'm a D3.js newbie, so I beg your pardon if I ask something too basic.

I have a simple array as a dataset:

```
[0, 10, 15, 20, 24, 35, 58]
```

For every element of my array I want to create a circle and horizontally put those circles at the same distance (12 pixel) starting from x=10 (and y being constantly 50). How can I do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This [**site**](https://www.dashingd3js.com/adding-an-svg-element) might help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic things you need to know about `d3.js` is, it binds data to svg elements and creates visualization.

To get to the basics of d3. You can google around.

Here are some sites that I prefer for d3 learning.

[**d3**](http://d3js.org/) - Ofcourse the official website. With all the codes and examples.

---

[**Dashing D3**](https://www.dashingd3js.com/) - Free for basic and you can also get a paid extension for further d3 tutorials.

---

[**d3noob**](http://www.d3noob.org/) - You get a free PDF with all the line by line briefing in the PDF. The one I prefer the most for the beginners.

---

Here's the answer for the question - [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgD27/).

It's very simple on creating circles in d3.

Here's the code I've used.

```
var svg = d3.select('.circle')
        .append('svg')
        .attr('height', 500)
        .attr('width', 500)
```

First off I append the svg element to the `.circle` div.

```
svg.selectAll('circle')
.data(data)
.enter()
.append('circle')
.attr("cx", function(d, i) { return 60 * i })
.attr("cy", 60)
.attr("r", 20)
```

And then I add the circles depending on the number of data using the above block of code.

Note : `.attr` is that I'm adding attribute.

Here I've fixed the radius to `20`.

But you can change the radius according to the data like this. `function(d) { return d; }`.

And ofcourse you can color the circles by using `.style("fill", "#ddd")` and other css stuffs using `.style()`.

You can get more of this info from the websites I've provided.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is it possible to multiply a group (g) in the same way?

Comment: I didn't get you. `g` is a group tag. Why do you want to multipy something with a tag?

Comment: I must do the same you do with circles with a complex object (the object is inside a group)

Comment: Better open a new post for that with all the relevant codes and a fiddle. So that I'll be able to help you and I'll get a clear understanding on what you required..