# how to display rowchart in dc.js

Tags: d3.js, dc.js

I'm making a rowchart using the Dimensional Charting javascript library dc.js, which is based on d3 and crossfilter. i am displaying rowchart for us population. how to display top 10 counties population in us and top less 10 counties counties of popualtion.Thanx

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow is about helping peoples with what they've tried.

It doesn't encourage spoon feeding.

Here's a [**list**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212962/d3-js-position-elements-horizontally/23213305#23213305) of few website which will you help you through the basic blocks of d3.

Moving onto `dc.js`. It is a wonderful multi-dimensional charting javascript library.

[**dc.js**](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/) - Here's the official website.

---

[**Annotated Source**](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html) - For the charts in the `dc.js` website.

---

[**Code Project**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/693841/Making-Dashboards-with-Dc-js-Part-Using-Crossfil) - And here's another website where I learned step by step dc.js.

---

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NmWP8/5/) - For creating a pie chart using `dc.js`.

---

**Steps :**

**You need to load the following libraries and css files -**

```
d3.js
crossfilter.js
dc.js
dc.css
```

**This code is using the crossfilter js.**

```
var ndx = crossfilter(data);
```

**Here I'm parsing the data.**

```
var parseDate = d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y").parse;

data.forEach(function(d) {
    d.date = parseDate(d.date);
    d.total= d.http_404+d.http_200+d.http_302;
        d.Year=d.date.getFullYear();
});
```

**Here we are creating a dimension for the year and we get the sum of `total` column.**

```
var yearDim  = ndx.dimension(function(d) {return +d.Year;});
var year_total = yearDim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return d.total;});
```

**And through this block of code we create a pie chart in the div.**

```
var yearRingChart   = dc.pieChart("#chart-ring-year");

yearRingChart
    .width(150).height(150)
    .dimension(yearDim)
    .group(year_total)
    .innerRadius(30);
```

**Finally at the end of all the charts we create, this is the code that renders all the chart to the browser.**

```
dc.renderAll();
```

To make a row chart just simply change the pie chart to row chart something like this.

```
var yearRingChart   = dc.rowChart("#chart-ring-year");
```

And remove the `innerRadius` property which we do not have for a row chart.

```
yearRingChart
    .width(150).height(150)
    .dimension(yearDim)
    .group(year_total)
```

By changing it you'll be having a row chart.

And here's a complete [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/NmWP8/6/) with a `rowChart`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, anonymous spoon-feeder ;)
You are very patient.  I wouldn't have tried.

Comment: That's nice answer. Not sure why the fiddles don't seem to work for me today.