# D3.js, multiply element <g>

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm D3.js newbie. I'm trying to duplicate an SVG group but I can't understand how to correctly do it. This is my group:

```
// external <g>
var group = svg.append("g");
group.attr("class", "myGroup");
group.append('circle')
.attr({cx:20,cy:100,r:4,fill:'black','fill-opacity':1,stroke:'red','stroke-width':0});

// inner <g> with line and text
var groupLine = group.append('g');
groupLine.append('line')
.attr({x1:20,y1:100,x2:20,y2:20,stroke:'black','stroke-width':0.4});
groupLine.append('text')
.text('texttext')
.attr({x:200,y:200,'text-anchor':'start','transform':'translate(-182,294) rotate(-90)'})
.style("font-family","Verdana")
.style("font-size","12px");
```

(fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/n7Qs3/)

Now, based on a simple array ([D3.js, position elements horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23212962/d3-js-position-elements-horizontally)), I want to multiply this group, creating 6 groups and position them horizontally. Basicly, the idea is the same as the ancient Flash `duplicateMovieClip`.

How can I do?

Comment: The attributes you are defining is wrong. All the attribute labels must be wrapped inside double quotes like this `attr({"cx":20})`. And that's not happening here. And if I'm not wrong, here you wanted to create groups based on the number of data in array right?

Comment: @UnknownUser: no problem, I'll correct it (even if what I did at the moment seems to work). And, yes, I want to multiply that object but how? I'm just asking this...   :-)  Anyway, I found many resources with cx without quotes (eg: http://enjalot.github.io/intro-d3/html5devconf/binding/)

Comment: Thanks. I learnt something new. Check if [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/jgD27/1/) helps. Here there are number of groups created depending on the number of data in the array.

Comment: I know how to multiply circles, but thanks anyway   :-)

Comment: You got what you were looking for?

Comment: No, because I knew how to do this. What I don't know is how you can multiply <g> elements and if it is possible (being to create a sort of blueprint symbol to derive other "copies" of it). Can you provide me with the same example applied to my group?

Comment: I don't know what you want to multiply the `<g>` elements with. I don't know whether you clear on your question or I'm not clear on your clear. Try providing a fiddle it'll be helpful even for others to help you on this.

Comment: Your example multiplies unnecessary svg elements. I want to multiply <g> elements with a particular class name. I tried to modify your example to fit my needs but I get lots of console errors. So: how you multiply g elements the way one could multiply basic circles?

Comment: You now want to create 6 `g` tags and each consisting of one circle huh?

Comment: No, each group .myGroup contains another group and other things. I want to multiply the outer group (and of course all its contents).

Comment: @UnknownUser: this is (for completeness) how I modified your code (it doesn't work): `d3.select("svg").selectAll(".myGroup")
    .data([4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42])
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "myGroup")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) { return 60 * i })
    .attr({"y":10})
    .append('circle')
    .attr({'cx':20,'cy':100,'r':4,fill:'black','fill-opacity':1,'stroke':'red','stroke-width':0});`

Comment: Actually I didn't understand your question at all. And you provided the fiddle very late and didn't see it. By the way providing fiddle did help others to answer it. Henceforth please do post with relevant code and a fiddle which will make the post easier for others to read.

Comment: @UnknownUser: you're wrong: I provided the fiddle before you could even reply. Lars understood the question, anyway. My idea is one can't duplicate <g> elements the way you do with other elements (circles and so on). If interested, I posted here too: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/d3-js/xEIvd1nFf5w

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built into D3 for this, but you can use [`.cloneNode()`](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/met_element_clonenode.asp):

```
var newNode = group.node().cloneNode(true);
svg.append(function() { return newNode; });
```

The only thing you need to do is set the offset for each copy:

```
newNode.setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + (i * 100) + ",0)");
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/n7Qs3/1/).

Comment: Ok, this is what I was looking for, thanks. Is it possible to use cloneNode without looping (that is, using the preferred d3.js syntax, as shown in UnknownUser fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jgD27/1/)?

Comment: Well you'll have to run the code to clone each time. You could however clone inside the `.append()`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Lars  :-)  It would be nice to have a D3 feature that lets you build a Custom Symbol and reuse it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I 'clone' multiple buttons.

```
    d3.select("#some_id")
      .append("div")
      .attr("class","some_other_id")
      .each(function(d) {

    for (var i = 1; i < number_to_duplicate; i++) {
        d3.select("#some_other_id")
          .append("button")
          .attr("type","button")
          .attr("class","btn-btn")
          .attr("id",function(d) { return 'button '+i;})
          .append("div")
          .attr("class","label")
          .text(function(d) { return 'button '+i;})
    }
    };)
```

I create  div and .each(function). Int the function the for loop creates the buttons.

For your purposes you would change the attributes including (x: x times i) for positioning.
But anyway this is my very simple solution to make buttons or similar elements with different ids.
Labels could be attached outside the loop.

So I guess you could do: create a  div, attach .each, invoke a function in each containing the for loop, using i as multiplier for the position:

```
    .each(function(d) {

    for (var i = 1; i < number_to_duplicate; i++) {
     d3.select("#some_other_id")
       .append('line')
       .attr({x1:20*i,y1:100,x2:20*i,y2:20,stroke:'black','stroke-width':0.4});
       .text('texttext')
       .attr({x:200*i,y:200,'text anchor':'start','transform':'translate(-182,294) rotate(-90)'})
       .style("font-family","Verdana")
       .style("font-size","12px");
    }
    };)
```